# How To get Image URL From PHAsset? Is it possible To save Image using PHAsset URL to document Directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsdata, phphotolibrary

I used

```objectivec
NSURL *urlA = [info valueForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
```

but when i try to save image using URL then URL is nil.

```objectivec
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlA options:NSDataReadingMapped error:nil];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

asset = Here you have to pass your PHAsset .

```
PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
 [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
             requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                            options:imageRequestOptions
                      resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                                      UIImageOrientation orientation, 
                                      NSDictionary *info) 
     {
          NSLog(@"info = %@", info);
          if ([info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]) {

               NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
               // if you want to save image in document see this.
               [self saveimageindocument:imageData withimagename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DEMO"]];
          }                                            
    }];

-(void) saveimageindocument:(NSData*) imageData withimagename:(NSString*)imagename{

    NSString *writePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",[Utility getDocumentDirectory],imagename];

    if (![imageData writeToFile:writePath atomically:YES]) {
        // failure
        NSLog(@"image save failed to path %@", writePath);

    } else {
        // success.
        NSLog(@"image save Successfully to path %@", writePath);
    }

}
+ (NSString*)getDocumentDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Check image that landscape mode or portrait mode

```
if (chooseimage.size.height >= chooseimage.size.width)
{
         Islandscape = NO;
}else{
     UIImage* landscapeImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:chooseimage.CGImage
                                                      scale:chooseimage.scale
                                                orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
        self.imgPreviewView.image = landscapeImage;
        self.imgPreviewView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        Islandscape = YES;
 }
```

Add this permission into info.plist file

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your photo library to let you select a picture.</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for ans
i tried your ans but i receive this type error print on log::setting security information: Operation not permitted
and also I try to save image from Phasset URL to document Direcory , but I get The error - access not allow due to security reason.

Comment: you have to add one thing in info.plist file that is i added in my answer. @KeyurAspiration

Comment: i already added in info.plist like Photo,Camera,MicroPhone Description Access , one more thing ant other way array of images save into document directory with out memory warning  issue.so please tell me.

Comment: @KeyurAspiration check my updated answer that store image in document folder

Comment: one more things can you help me?. I can get Image but portrait image shown in landscape.

Comment: then write code for it landscape image to portraint

Comment: @Himunshu-Moradiya thanks for last time reply one more thing i want your help for resolve my app crash issue show below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778361/gatekeeperxpc-connection-to-assetsd-was-interrupted-or-assetsd-died-on-using-ima

Comment: @KeyurAspiration in that question you have problem with image array that store value and when you process on image so its crush

Comment: I know this problem occurs but how to handle it, can you describe?

Comment: @KeyurAspiration the image you display is you getting from server throw any API ?

Comment: Images not getting from a server it was picked from photo library using image picker library.

Comment: imageRequestOptions is really necessary? maybe put nil does the same.

Comment: @jose920405 we have to pass imageRequestOptions Object in that method that why i create one instance first and then pass in method

Answer (score 13):

You can get the imageURL from [PHContentEditingInput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phcontenteditinginput):

Swift:

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (eidtingInput, info) in
  if let input = eidtingInput, let imgURL = input.fullSizeImageURL {
     // imgURL 
  }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new] completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
    NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
}];
```

Comment: @a-tuo please answer in Objective-C becauase i have no idea in Swift

Comment: @KeyurAspiration Have you add the "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" key in plist to get the permission of accessing Photos?

Comment: @a-tuo Yes, i already given this "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"

Comment: Not working for me (iOS 14.4) PHImageFileURLKey not included in dictionary.

Comment: The property of 'isNetworkAccessAllowed' needs to be set with true, if the image is not in local. See full code: ```let requestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
                        requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                        asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: requestOptions) { (editingInput, info) in }```

Answer (score -1):

//This is the Complete Swift Code of getting image URL with PHAsset answer of Himanshu Moradiya

```
  let imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
  PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: currentAsset, options: imageRequestOptions, resultHandler: { imageData, dataUTI, orientation, info in
    if let info = info {
      print("info = \(info)")
    }
    if info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] != nil {

      let path = info?["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? URL
       print(path) //here you get complete URL


      // if you want to save image in document see this.
     // self.saveimageindocument(imageData, withimagename: "DEMO")
    }
  })
```